# How to customize Yii 2 RBAC table names

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Is there anyway that we can change the RBAC table names in yii 2?

i configured the authManager as below,

```
'authManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    'assignmentTable'=> '{{%AuthAssignment}}',
    'itemChildTable'=> '{{%AuthItemChild}}',
    'itemTable'=> '{{%AuthItem}}',
    'ruleTable'=> '{{%AuthRule}}',
    'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
],
```

Now i need to know how to customize the column names as well. yii by default queries to default column names, so i am getting this error.

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rule_name' in 'field list'
```

below is how my table structure differs with yii 2 default RBAC tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuthRule` (
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `data` text,
  `createdAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuthItemChild` (
  `parent` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `child` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuthItem` (
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `ruleName` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` text,
  `createdAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `AuthAssignment` (
  `itemName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `userId` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for advanced template

In your config/main.hp

in component section

```
'components' => [
        'authManager' => [
        //'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        'class' => 'vendor\yourVenderName\auth\models\DbManager',           
        'cache' => 'cache',
        //these configuratio allow to rename the auth table  
        'itemTable' => 'my_auth_item',
        'assignmentTable' => 'my_auth_assignment',
        'itemChildTable' => 'my_auth_item_child',
        'ruleTable' => 'my_auth_rule',
    ],

 ....
],
```

use the proper class for your need 
in this case i use a vendor authmanager, but yuou can use the standard one uncommeting the standard `'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',` and commetting the vendor one